# Python: Getting a a proper list out of lines in a file

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the folllowing line of code

```
name = input("Enter file:")

if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)

for line in handle:

    if line.startswith('From '):

        value= (line.split()[1])

        print(value)
```

And as a output I get the mails adresses in the text file in the following format:

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za 

louis@media.berkeley.edu

zqian@umich.edu

rjlowe@iupui.edu

zqian@umich.edu

rjlowe@iupui.edu

gsilver@umich.edu

gsilver@umich.edu

zqian@umich.edu
```

Does anybody know how to get the output in a normal list format like ['louis@media.berkeley.edu' , 'rjlowe@iupui.edu' ......]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure if you just want to replicate the output format of Python lists or actually want a Python list. If the latter is true, I would suggest you looking into `list.append()` or `list` comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Comprehension:

```
name = input("Enter file:")

if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)

value= [line.split()[1] for line in handle if line.startswith('From ')] 

print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the easiest way to do that is:

```
handle = open(name, "r")
content = handle.read()
content_list = content.split("\n\n")
handle.close()
print(content_list)
```